# Discord.js: Says there are no messages in a channel which does have messages

Tags: discord.js

Here is my code

```
import Discord from 'discord.js'

const bot = new Discord.Client()
const channelID = 'the channel's id'

bot.login('my token')

bot.on('ready', async () => {
    const channel = (await bot.channels.fetch(channelID)) as Discord.TextChannel //im using typescript

    console.log(channel.messages.cache.array())
})
```

For some reason the array is empty, even though there are tons of messages in the channel. Any reason this might be? I know that it is getting the right channel, as I've tested that and it shows the right server and name. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `channel.messages.fetch().array()` instead. Your array is most likely empty because the messages are not cached, optionally you can also cache the messages by doing `channel.messages.fetch({}, true).array()`